# How do I know if I should divide or subtract cases to remove over counting in combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

Sometimes I do questions where I divide my answer by a factor to remove excess counting and sometimes do subtraction. Now, I wonder, would both methods be equivalent? Because I definitely think we can just pluck out unfavourable cases from the total cases by subtraction instead of dividing. However is the converse true could we plug out cases that we subtract by division?

And finally as a bonus, are there other methods of case removal?

Examples: 1. 30 people in room hand shake each other, find the number of handshakes done
2. ways to p ick three items from a set of 'n' and put into three slots ( you divide by 3! on this one)

Comment: Do you mind adding an example?

Comment: I tried putting some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether your count is too high because of a **known quantity** or a **known factor**. Some examples might clarify.

1. Ten people like strawberry ice cream, twenty like chocolate, and five like both. How many people are there in total? An estimate would be be $10 + 20$ (strawberry plus chocolate), but this **overcounts by a known quantity** (the five who like both). You would correct this overcount with subtraction: $10 + 20 - 5$.
2. There are ten people in a room and each one shakes hands with each other person. How many handshakes take place? An estimate would be $10 \cdot 9$ (each of the ten people needs to shake hands with nine other people), but this **overcounts by a known factor** (every handshake is getting counted twice). You would correct this with division: $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10 \cdot 9$.

Comment: I know in the second case, we could reduce by 10*9/2 but in first case could we have a factor to 'fix it'?

Comment: I don't see any reasonable interpretation of division that works in problem 1. Notice that in problem 2, every single handshake has its "duplicate" handshake ("person A shakes person B" is the same as "person B shakes person A"), so we want to put these two handshakes into a group and select just one of them (this is one way to define division). In problem 1, there really are some people who just like strawberry ice cream, so we have nothing to "pair" them with. It's more straightforward to delete (via subtraction) the five duplicate cases.