# To divide or not to divide: Reducing repeat cases in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**:

> Find the number of natural number solution of the equation: $$x+y+z+4w=37$$

**My attempt**:

> I'll use: $^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$
> We have, effectively, $x+y+z+4w=30$
> Since, $4$ "boxes/lots" are same/alike/identical, and $n=30,r=7$
> $$\therefore \text {Answer} =\frac{^{36}C_6}{4!}$$

**Video Solution**:

> $1\leq w\leq8$, we'll make different cases and use: $^{n-1}C_{r-1}$
> If $w=1$; $\quad x+y+z=33$; $\quad^{33-1}C_{3-1}$ $=$ $^{32}C_{2}$
> If $w=2$; $\quad x+y+z=29$; $\quad^{29-1}C_{3-1}$ $=$ $^{28}C_{2}$
> $\dots$
> If $w=8$; $\quad x+y+z=5$; $\quad^{5-1}C_{3-1}$ $=$ $^4C_{2}$
> $$\therefore\text{Answer=} ^{32}C_{2}{+}^{28}C_{2}{+}^{24}C_{2}+\dots{+}^4C_{2}$$

**My doubt**:

> 1. Why my way of doing is wrong?
> 2. How do I know that when not to do what I did? [Because when I not do it, then I over-work/take fool's way instead of smart way. And when I do it then such cases as this happen]

Please help.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  You can't treat the $4w$ box as $4$ separate boxes for a number of reasons (not least that the contents of those $4$ boxes might not sum to a multiple of $4$).

Comment: As a quick way to see the problem, note that the number of solutions to $4a=7$ is $0$ but there are many solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=7$.

Comment: @lulu that didn't make it quite clear as 4 terms may equal 7 in many ways but we can't distinguish one from other that's why I divided by $4!$ but "$4a=7$ is $0$" I didn't quite get it's relevance.

Comment: It is important to note as well the difference between $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ (*which counts non-negative solutions*) and $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ (*which counts positive solutions*).  The "video solution" used $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ which implies to me that they do not want any "empty boxes", that they do not treat zero as a natural number.  Your attempt used $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ which would imply you *do* treat zero as a natural number (*or forgot*).  If you want to allow zeroes then the video's solution would need to be adjusted.

Comment: If my original equation was $4a=7$ then that equation would have no solutions, right?  Since $7$ is not a multiple of $4$.  However, your method clearly yields a non-zero number, as there are solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=7$, and non-zero numbers are still non-zero even after you divide by $4!$

Comment: @JMoravitz no one forgot 0 and natural numbers don't include 0. 1 has been subtracted for each variable so that they may then be considered whole numbers.

Comment: @lulu in your example, neither the video, nor myself would would use that formula to calculate the number of ways. That's what I think. But if you can tell how the video will apply the same method on your example, then I'll get most likely understand. Kindly not use, "clearly answer is $0$".

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you honestly not see that there are no natural number solutions to $4a=7$?  And why is it that you imagine that your idea would apply to the problem you stated but not to this one?  The same reason that the idea fails for my example explains why it fails for yours.

Comment: @lulu I see it, obviously. But I don't see myself nor the video applying the formula to your example. Kindly understand that I'm trying to understand. I'm not opposed to your example.

Comment: But, if you want an example closer to the one you gave, use $a+4b=7$ which actually has solutions over the natural numbers.  We easily see that $b<2$ which means that the only possible case is $b=1$, which leads to the unique solutiion $(a,b)=(3,1)$.  Your method, however, yields $\frac 1{4!}\times \binom {7+4}4=13.75$ which isn't even an integer.

Comment: @lulu I know my method yields a wrong answer. But why? I too tried for a simpler number as $x+y+z+4w=11$ and observed that while video will arrive at 16, my method would yield $\frac{35}4$.

Comment: For the reason I gave, among others.  To be correct, your method would need to insist that the four virtual boxes each contain the same value.  That would be a true equivalent to the original problem, but of course it is no easier to solve than the original.

Comment: After all, which of your cases would, say, $w=2$ correspond to?  Would it be $(2,2,2,2)$?  Or $(5,1,1,1)$?   Or $(4,2,1,1)$?  Or $(3,3,1,1)$?

Comment: As a general point:  if you are given counting problem $A$ and wish to solve it by changing it into counting problem $B$, then you must explain (in detail) the connection between the two problems.  Maybe there's a bijection between the solutions, maybe one problem is somehow the complement of the other.  But the connection is the key and it must be explained.  Here, I see no useful connection between the two problems.

Comment: @lulu Wow! Now that's what I'm talking about. Had you provided that example of (2,2,2,2) or (5,1,1,1) earlier I would have right then understood. Also, I'll need to inspect in greater detail the seemingly very helpful last comment. If anything seems not right to me I'll come back here. That said, you might consider posting especially the last 2 comments as an answer. I'll upvote them as they're humungously helpful. But after inspection is complete I'll consider to "tick-mark" it (cet. par.). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  Good luck.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770284/how-do-i-know-if-i-should-divide-or-subtract-cases-to-remove-over-counting-in-co

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational thank you. It was useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note***: It's been quite some time since posting the question and OP found the following comments by the user: ***lulu*** very helpful. So, they have been compiled here as an answer.

---

This is hard to follow. You can't treat the $4w$ box as $4$ separate boxes for a number of reasons (not least that the contents of those $4$ boxes might not sum to a multiple of $4$).

As a quick way to see the problem, note that the number of solutions to $4a=7$ is $0$ but there are many solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=7$.

If my original equation was $4a=7$ then that equation would have no solutions, since $7$ is not a multiple of $4$. However, your method clearly yields a non-zero number, as there are solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=7$, and non-zero numbers are still non-zero even after you divide by $4!$

But, if you want an example closer to the one you gave, use $a+4b=7$ which actually has solutions over the natural numbers. We easily see that $b<2$ which means that the only possible case is $b=1$, which leads to the unique solution $(a,b)=(3,1)$. Your method, however, yields $14!×(7+44)=13.75$ which isn't even an integer.

To be correct, your method would need to insist that the four virtual boxes each contain the same value. That would be a true equivalent to the original problem, but of course it is no easier to solve than the original.

After all, which of your cases would, say, $w=2$ correspond to? Would it be $(2,2,2,2)$? Or $(5,1,1,1)$? Or $(4,2,1,1)$? Or $(3,3,1,1)$?

**As a general point**: if you are given counting problem $A$ and wish to solve it by changing it into counting problem $B$, then you must explain (in detail) the connection between the two problems. Maybe there's a bijection between the solutions, maybe one problem is somehow the complement of the other. But the connection is the key and it must be explained. Here, I see no useful connection between the two problems.

Answer (score 1):

- Note that there are differing definitions of natural numbers (see link). The book has taken it to be positive integers, let us go with that
- The stars and bars formula then simplifies to $\Large\binom{n-1}{k-1}$
- To come to your main difficulty, in the equation $x+y+z+4w=37$, we can't take the last term to comprise of four separate boxes, because for every increase of $1$ for $w$, the total increases by $4$. So if we are to use stars and bars, we shall have to do it case by case, starting upwards with $w=1$ , other variables $\geq 1$

[https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html#:~:text=The%20term%20%22natural%20number%22%20refers,Bourbaki%201968%2C%20Halmos%201974](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20%22natural%20number%22%20refers,Bourbaki%201968%2C%20Halmos%201974)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upvoted. Natural may be whole numbers! What's the use of having whole numbers then(?!). Also, is there someone way to prevent myself from repeating such a mistake in other questions as I asked in $2^{nd}$ question, it would be great to have some flags indicating that.

Comment: Simple stars and bars will be in the form $x_1+x_2+ x_3+..=N$ If a coefficient other than 1 is attached to  variable(s), you'll need to think it out as here, or use generating functions.

Comment: "think it out as here": what is "here" referring to?

Comment: Here as in the problem $x+y+z+\color\red{4}w = 37$, where one variable has a coefficient of $4$

Comment: Alright, now clear. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome !$\;\;$:)